# Using classes , parameters, objects with Scanner input

Tags: java

I have a class City.java and State.java with automatically generated constructors, getters and setters (if needed I can add them to the question).

In `Main.java` my task is to get information with `Scanner` as input and make objects with all the information written in.

Data input for each object is needed to be taken out in separate methods that will be eventually called from main method. Each of these methods must return the object that fills. It's allowed to only one object of class `Scanner`.

```
public Class City { 
   private String name;
   private Bigdecimal surface;
   //+constructor , + getters and setters
}
public Class State {
   private String name;
   private City city;
 //+constructor , + getters and setters
}

public class Main {

    public static City city (Scanner scanner) {
       System.out.println("Store City name : ");
       String cityName = scanner.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Store City surface : ");
       BigDecimal citySurface = scanner.nextBigDecimal();

    return new City(cityName,citySurface);
    }

    public static State state (Scanner scanner){
      System.out.println("Store State name : ");
      String stateName = scanner.nextLine();
```

I'm lost at this point. The task is that I should return new 
State with parameters (stateName,City) but I can't figure out
how to pass the previously entered city here as a parameter.

```
      }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner mainScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can call `city`, then pass its `City` result as an additional parameter to the `state` method ?

Comment: Not an answer but an advice : you should explicitely prefix your methods like this `public static City askCity(Scanner scanner)` to avoid getting confused by your own code later on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
public class Main {

  public static City city (Scanner scanner) {
   System.out.println("Store City name : ");
   String cityName = scanner.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Store City surface : ");
   BigDecimal citySurface = scanner.nextBigDecimal();

   return new City(cityName,citySurface);
  }

  public static State state (Scanner scanner, City city){
    System.out.println("Store State name : ");
    String stateName = scanner.nextLine();
    //Do stuff here with city e.g. city.getName()
    return new State(stateName, city);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner mainScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    City myCity = city(scanner);
    state(mainScanner, myCity);
    //I'm sure you could also do this code in shorthand like below because of the callstack order.
    //state(mainScanner, city(scanner));
  }

}
```

You just need to pass the city object through to the state and then handle the code that should happen once you have it. To be honest I don't think you should have those methods there in the Main class and as statics and stuff, but that is another issue entirely.

Comment: If I am incorrect in my answer. You could at least put a comment and say why rather than just downvoting.

Comment: I agree with your comment. You probably forgot to write `return new State(statename, city);` in the state() method.

Comment: @WholeBrain Ahhh yes I see what you mean. It's not that I forgot, it's more like I implied it would be there in that section, in the comment where I wrote `//Do stuff here with city e.g. city.getName()` but I see how it would have been better to add it in instead. I will amend that per your feedback, thanks.